# Extraneous arguments to set style line

Tags: gnuplot

I run the following script (only the main part of the script is shown)

```
# set-up
nutc = 1.0 # torque

# legend
set key top right

# 1st x axis
set xlabel 't in d^2/{/Symbol n}'
set format x "%.1f"
set xrange [0.0: 1.0]
set xtics   0.0, 0.5
set mxtics  2

# 1st y axis
set ylabel 'Nu_{/Symbol w}'
set format y "%.1f"
set yrange [-0.2:  3.0]
set ytics   -1.0,  1.0
set mytics   5

# grid lines
set nogrid

# line styles with colours appropriate for colour-blind
set style line 10 lc rgb '#000000' dt 2 lw 1.5 # black
set style line 11 lc rgb '#D55E00' dt 1 lw 1.5 # vermillon
set style line 12 lc rgb '#0072B2' dt 1 lw 1.5 # blue
set style line 13 lc rgb '#009E73' dt 1 lw 1.5 # bluish green
set style line 14 lc rgb '#E69F00' dt 1 lw 1.5 # orange
set style line 15 lc rgb '#56B4E9' dt 1 lw 1.5 # sky blue
set style line 16 lc rgb '#CC79A7' dt 1 lw 1.5 # reddish purple
set style line 17 lc rgb '#F0E442' dt 1 lw 1.5 # yellow 

# main plot
set style data lines
plot nutc t 'solution' ls 10,\
     'torque' u ($1):($2) t 'Inner' ls 11,\
     'torque' u ($1):($3) t 'Outer' ls 12

# convert to pdf (epstopdf comes with e.g. TeXlive)
system('epstopdf '.file)
```

Upon running it pops up the following error

[image]

What is the reason for the error and how to fix it? [I suppose the same issue exists for all the 8 lines in the line style setup section: lines 43-50]

Comment: I have no idea, I typed "which gnuplot" in the terminal and it only shows "/bin/gnuplot
" without a specific version number.

Comment: I just did that and it shows "Version 4.6 patchlevel 2  last modified 2013-03-14"

Comment: Yes, I only get this error message with gnuplot 4.x versions. This version is about 10 years old. Can't you update to a newer version? gnuplot is now at 5.4 or 5.5 or even 6.0.

Comment: I see, is there a terminal command for an update to a better version?

Comment: Download the desired version from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/

Comment: Cool, I will have that upgraded. A related question: I deleted the line style setting for now and run the script again, it then shows an error saying "sh: epstopdf: command not found".  Does that mean epstopdf needs to be installed separately? (it has generated an .eps file but not with a pdf)  Or is that epstopdf already equipped in a better version of gnuplot?

Comment: as it says in your sctript `epstopdf` comes with e.g. TeXlive. It is a separate program and not part of gnuplot. But why don't you simply generate PDFs directly, i.e. `set terminal pdfcairo`. In the gnuplot console type `set term` to get a list of available terminals.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I need eps file for preparing a manuscript for publication, so both eps and pdf are needed. I will have a better version of gnuplot as well as TeXlive installed, hopefully those will make the original script work then.

Comment: Please post code and errors as code-formatted text not as screenshots.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: format of the coding part of the post has been fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the StackOverflow rules "no answers in the comments", let me summarize:

You have a pretty old gnuplot version 4.6.2 (2013) which does not allow setting dashtype (`dt`) in the line style settings. Maybe there is a different approach or a workaround, but probably the easiest would be if you update to a newer version of gnuplot, see: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/

In the gnuplot console type `set term` and you will see the available terminals. That's what I get:

```
Available terminal types:
       cairolatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package and Cairo backend
           canvas  HTML Canvas object
              cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
          context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
          domterm  DomTerm terminal emulator with embedded SVG
             dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
              dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
              emf  Enhanced Metafile format
         epscairo  eps terminal based on cairo
         epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
              fig  FIG graphics language V3.2 for XFIG graphics editor
              gif  GIF images using libgd and TrueType fonts
             hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
             jpeg  JPEG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
              lua  Lua generic terminal driver
               mf  Metafont plotting standard
               mp  MetaPost plotting standard
             pcl5  PCL5e/PCL5c printers using HP-GL/2
         pdfcairo  pdf terminal based on cairo
           pict2e  LaTeX2e picture environment
              png  PNG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
         pngcairo  png terminal based on cairo
       postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
          pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
            pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
         pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros
               qt  Qt cross-platform interactive terminal
          sixelgd  sixel using libgd and TrueType fonts
              svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics
          texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment
             tikz  TeX TikZ graphics macros via the lua script driver
         tkcanvas  Tk canvas widget
          unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device
          windows  Microsoft Windows
              wxt  wxWidgets cross-platform interactive terminal
```

For your purpose, check `help cairolatex`, `help epscairo`, `help epslatex` and `help pdfcairo`.